# Flutter : Client application unable to discover the server on local network

Tags: flutter, dart

I have recently started with Flutter android mobile app development and I am trying to create 2 applications (server and client) for transferring data in a bidirectional way. Below is the code snippet for the Server which is trying to bind on localhost, Client application uses ping_discover_network package to ping and discovers the device and main which calls the getIpAddress method for assigning the IP address. However, the getIpAddress method seems to be not pinging any device because the address variable is always null. Really appreciate it if someone could help me and address any issue with my code.

`Server:`

```
Future<void> start() async {
    runZoned(() async {
        server = await ServerSocket.bind('127.0.0.1', 4000);
        running = true;
        server!.listen(onRequest);
        const message = "Server is listening on port 4000";
        onData!(Uint8List.fromList(message.codeUnits));
    }, onError: onError);
}
```

`Client:`

```
getIpAddress() {
    stream = NetworkAnalyzer.discover2('127.0.0', port);
    stream!.listen((NetworkAddress networkAddress) {
        if(networkAddress.exists) {
            address = networkAddress;
            clientModel = ClientModel(
            hostname: networkAddress.ip, 
            onData: onData, 
            onError: onError, 
            port: port);
        }
    });

    update();
}
```

`Main:`

```
children: [
    if(controller.address == null)
        Text("No Device Found")
    else
        Column(
            children: [
                const Text("Desktop",
                    style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                )),
                Text(controller.address!.ip,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                )),
            ],
        )
],
```

I have tried all the possible ways. When I am trying to use the IPv4 IP on the Server side to bind its giving me errors like (Error: SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Cannot assign requested address, errno = 99), address = 192.168.1.104, port = 52379)

When I am using localhost the device is not discovered by the Client.

Comment: use `10.0.2.2` instead of `127.0.0.1` when connecting an emulator or android device.

Comment: Iam not able to create server socket on this IP. Below is the error message
Error: SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Cannot assign requested address, errno = 99), address = 10.0.2.2, port = 4000